# Launching Angular + ASP.Net Core Application causes 'The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html''

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, ubuntu, deployment, web-deployment

I am interested in deploying my ASP.NET Core Application with a Angular Frontend on my Ubuntu Linux VPS. I am using a Nginx-Proxy, but this should not have any impact on this issue (it works as intended). The issue I am facing is propably due to root-folders and linux execution root paths.

**What is the issue?**

When launching my app from inside the folder the .dll-file is located in with `dotnet MyApp.dll` it works perfectly fine and is also reachable from the outside via browser.

But when executing with a daemon/systemd with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/MyApp/MyApp.dll` it returns the following error. This also happens when launching with the same command from the root folder (~#).

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
      Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__1(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<Use>b__2()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__0(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HstsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]
      An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
      Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__1(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<Use>b__2()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__0(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HstsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HMA8CR3IGQIJ", Request id "0HMA8CR3IGQIJ:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
      Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.

         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__1(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_2.<Use>b__2()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.SpaDefaultPageMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Attach>b__0(HttpContext context, Func`1 next)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Use>b__1(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HstsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Many other Threads mention this passage in Startup.cs, but that remains unchanged:

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to the Content-Root/Working-Directory when executing the .dll-file from outside its folder (e.g. a systemd).
This was resolved by adding `WorkingDirectory=/path/to/app` to my systemd-service